# What is the best way to reverse port forward information from a Kubernetes cluster to localhost?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ports

I am attempting to reverse port forward information from a Kubernetes pod **192.168.49.2:30085** to my **locoalhost:8000** but I am having issues.

The goal is to get the same response as `curl 192.168.49.2:30085`  on localhost:8000

One thing I have tried has been using [ktunnel](https://github.com/omrikiei/ktunnel) with the command `ktunnel expose <service_name> 30085:8000` to try to forward this info. Doing this I get the output

```
INFO[0000] Exposed service's cluster ip is: 10.101.77.99
.INFO[0000] waiting for deployment to be ready
.....
INFO[0001] port forwarding to https://192.168.49.2:8443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/thisisatest-59d5584c84-b5qrc/portforward
INFO[0001] Waiting for port forward to finish
INFO[0001] Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:28688 -> 28688
INFO[2022-08-03 20:23:48.605] starting tcp tunnel from source 30085 to target 8000
```

Which seems normal and I am able to get a response when using `curl http://10.101.77.99:30085`  on local host 8000 but not the correct response.

I have also attempted to run a tcp server with the [command](https://webapp.io/blog/container-tcp-tunnel/) `nc 127.0.0.1 8000 | kubectl exec -i <pod_name> tcpserver 127.0.0.1 30085 cat` But am having poor results as well. Am I using these services incorrectly? Or is there a better way to do this all together?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to `kubectl`, try

`kubectl port-forward service/<servicename> 8000:30085`.

Answer (score 0):

Expose SSH on the pod and use SSH to do the reverse port forward

or

Use a service on the cluster pointing at your machine but that assumes the networking is connected some how

Those 2 anwsers were taken from this duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666273/forward-traffic-from-kubernetes-pod-to-local-server

I think a third better approach might be to use somekinda mesh VPN like https://tailscale.com/